# GALAXY S6 HOTSPOT AND TETHERING ICON MISSING

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 and I can't find the Mobile Hotspot and Tethering Icon on my device. I have tried dialing ##72786# but to no
 avail. Any help please

Comment: Wrong Site....it is for the Developers...you will be downvoted

Comment: Post your question here [Android Stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps. It was known as the solution.

From the home screen, tap Phone.
Dial ##72786#.

Note: If the dialer does not appear, tap the Dialer icon.

Tap YES.

The device will restart and initiate Hands Free Activation.

After the device restarts it will automatically perform Hands Free Activation.

Once the activation is complete, tap OK.

The device will then update the PRL. Once the update is complete, tap OK.

The device will check for firmware updates.

If an update is available, follow the prompts to download and install the update.

Otherwise, tap OK.

Tap OK.

The device will restart.

The network settings have been reset, and the device is now re-activated.

Comment: Hands Free Activation just keeps on saying Please wait and retrying but nothing is happening

Comment: Then probably you will have to contact Samsung customer care or visit one of branch and get it done.

Comment: What's samsung customer care dial number or email address?